# French special characters are not correctly rendering in BIRT report

Tags: report, translation, birt, french

I want to create a report in french language. I'm using birt-runtime-3_7_2. Report headings, table headers are configured in messages.properties file. The problem is when loading the report french special characters are not shown properly.

eg. Année is shown as AnnÃ©e in the report

I have changed birt locale as below in the web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>BIRT_VIEWER_LOCALE</param-name>
    <param-value>fr_FR</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And also changed fontsConfig.xml as below.

```
    <font-aliases>
            <mapping name="serif" font-family="Verdana" />
            <mapping name="sans-serif" font-family="Verdana" />
            <mapping name="monospace" font-family="Verdana" />
            <mapping name="cursive" font-family="Verdana" />
            <mapping name="fantasy" font-family="Verdana" />
    </font-aliases>

    <font-encodings>
            <encoding font-family="Verdana" encoding="UTF-8" />

    </font-encodings>
```

None of these get worked. How can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved the same issue for Russian translation. There's no need to change the fontConfig. The idea is that your .properties file must always be in the ISO 8859-1 character encoding. Characters that cannot be directly represented in this encoding can be written using Unicode escapes there. Example:

```
label_1 = \u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442
```

You can use cervices like [native2ascii](https://native2ascii.net/) to translate your text or symbols to escapes.